# Symfony Messenger component loses connection and duplicates saving records

Tags: symfony, symfony4

The scheme of work is as follows: I send json to the controller (then I convert json into an object) -> then I send the object to the queue (I use doctrines as a transport) -> then the handler reads the message and saves the object to the database. Problem: when processing messages asynchronously, several duplicates of the object are saved in the database + the handler writes about errors in the connection (see screenshot).

Found a description of this problem on symfony casts, they suggest using the flush function when saving an object to the database, without first using the persist function. With this approach, saving to the database does not occur.

With a synchronous save, this error does not occur.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

ApiController:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/api/task")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param MessageBusInterface $messageBus
 * @return Response
 */
public function createTask(Request $request, MessageBusInterface $messageBus): Response
{
    try {
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();

        $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(),
            InputCalculatorTaskDto::class,
            'json');

        $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto
            ->setTaskGuid(Uuid::uuid4())
            ->setServiceName(ServicesListEnum::SERVICE_CALULATOR)
            ->setTaskName(TaskListEnum::CALCULATE_ORDER_PRICE)
            ->setCreatedAt(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE)));

        $calculatorTaskMessage = new CalculatorTaskMessage($this->inputCalculatorTaskDto);
        $messageBus->dispatch($calculatorTaskMessage);

        $this->logger->info('done ' . $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto->getTaskGuid());

        return new Response('done');

    } catch (\Throwable $t) {
        $this->logger->error($t->getMessage());

        return new Response('error ' . $t->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Message:

```
class CalculatorTaskMessage
{
    /**
     * @var InputCalculatorTaskDto
     */
    private InputCalculatorTaskDto $inputCalculatorTaskDto;

    public function __construct(InputCalculatorTaskDto $inputCalculatorTaskDto)
    {
        $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto = $inputCalculatorTaskDto;
    }

    /**
     * @return InputCalculatorTaskDto
     */
    public function getInputCalculatorTaskDto(): InputCalculatorTaskDto
    {
        return $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto;
    }
}
```

MessageHandler

```
class CalculatorNewTaskCreatorHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public InputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntityImpl $inputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntity;
    public EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    public TasksRepository $tasksRepository;
    private CalculatorTaskProducer $calculatorTaskProducer;
    
    /**
        * CalculatorTaskCreatorHandler constructor.
        * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
        * @param TasksRepository $tasksRepository
        * @param CalculatorTaskProducer $calculatorTaskProducer
    */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    TasksRepository $tasksRepository,
    CalculatorTaskProducer $calculatorTaskProducer)
    {
        $this->inputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntity = new InputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntityImpl();
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->tasksRepository = $tasksRepository;
        $this->calculatorTaskProducer = $calculatorTaskProducer;
    }
    
    public function __invoke(CalculatorTaskMessage $calculatorTaskMessage)
    {
        $inputCalculatorTaskDto = $calculatorTaskMessage->getInputCalculatorTaskDto();
        $tasks = $this->inputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntity->map($inputCalculatorTaskDto);
        
        $this->entityManager->persist($tasks);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        
        $this->calculatorTaskProducer->sendMessage($inputCalculatorTaskDto);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a frustrating problem. Luckily, the solution to your duplication problem should be simple.

The problem that occurs is that when you publish your message to your queue and consuming it again from the queue, you are not using the same entity manager anymore. In your consumer part, Doctrine does not recognise the object anymore, and treats it like an unmanaged entity. That is why Doctrine is inserting multiple instances of the same thing.

**How you can fix this:**

In your consumer, do a lookup before you try to persist your object (from your message). If the entity is not found, you know it is a new entity and you can safely insert it.

If an existing entity is found, Doctrine understands that it already exists and will not insert it again. At this point you can update the values of the entity (if needed) and then persist & flush it. At this point, your entity should be updated and you should not have any duplications anymore.

Comment: thanks! I think it should work, but how do i search for an object in doctrine?

Comment: When you consume your message, you will have some data, i presume you will also have an unique identifier (id, slug, uuid...etc) with that you can use the correct entity repository and use `$repository->find($id)` or if you use and other field as identifier `$repository->findOneBy(['yourfield' => $id])`.

Comment: use ->refresh on entitymanager to make sure you have a valid copy, check the UnitOfWork for the state of the entity first to avoid reloading it unless needed